# .NET MVC - create model at runtime (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, runtime

Can I create new model at runtime? I have string with model's information and I need to create model according this string (at runtime).

I want to use it for access to various db tables, with structure defined in string variable as I mentioned.

Thanks.

Comment: Check these questions: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329461/how-to-create-controls-dynamically-in-mvc-3-based-on-an-xml-file AND
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588590/programmatically-adding-properties-to-an-mvc-model-at-runtime