# How to create asp.net page controls dynamically from xml?

Tags: asp.net, xml

For our web application project I want to dynamically create controls to a web page from XML.
Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Its all depends on your project need, about the configurations required

Create a control factory which produces a control on demand by reading XML configuration.

You may refer this [How to create controls dynamically in MVC 3 based on an XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329461/how-to-create-controls-dynamically-in-mvc-3-based-on-an-xml-file)

But it is coded for MVC, you start think about creating for Web Forms