# Add Controls Dynamically in ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, defaultmodelbinder

I've tried to follow the answer by Darin Dimitrov on this post:
[How to create controls dynamically in MVC 3 based on an XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329461/how-to-create-controls-dynamically-in-mvc-3-based-on-an-xml-file). But in ASP .NET Core (Specifically ASP .NET Core 2) there is no DefaultModelBinder so I have to modify the Custom Model Binder code in order to work with ASP .NET Core.

Actually my code is:

```
public class ControlModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var type = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".Type");
        object model = null;

        switch (type.FirstValue)
        {
            case "TextBox":
            {
                model = new TextBoxViewModel();
                break;
            }
            case "CheckBox":
            {
                model = new CheckBoxViewModel();
                break;
            }
            case "DropDownList":
            {
                model = new DropDownListViewModel();
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        };

        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(model.GetType());
        bindingContext.Model = model;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The problem that I'm having actually is that ModelMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType is showing me the error:

> It's required a reference for a non-static field, method or property
> 'ModelMetadataProviderGetMetadataForType(Type)'.

**So, What can I do in order to make work the model.GetType()?**

**How I can get ControllerContext and modelType?**

If someone knows how to convert this piece of code from ASP .NET MVC to ASP .NET Core I would really apreciate his help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't you need to create a new instance of your model instead of setting it to NULL?

Comment: In MVC 5, you can use `System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType()`, not sure if this works in .net core.